# Git: doing a pull doesn't automatically do a check out / get latest, right?

Tags: git

Could you confirm this:

With GIT when I do a pull a repository I still need to do a checkout after that to get the latest modifications on my working folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pull, you will get the latest remote version of your current branch to your local. Checkout is to change your current branch.

You might be confusing it with `git fetch`, when you fetch all branches from remote, and if there is a new branch with updates, you should checkout that new branch. This is an exapmle scenario where you need to checkout after getting it from remote.

Comment: Actually what I was misunderstanding is that the pull only pull the current branch, not all the repository.

Answer (score 2):

`$git pull` - will ensure your local copy is the same as the remote one.

However, sometimes it may ask you for specific branch to pull. You may try then:

```
$ git pull origin <Your_Branch_name>
```

This will merge the branch "Your_Branch_name" contents/changes to the current local git branch.

How ever a checkout to a different branch has to be explicitly made via the below command:

```
$ git checkout <branch>
$ git pull
```

or

```
$ git pull origin <branch_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, a pull will indeed get you the latest.

Answer (score 1):

git pull is equivalent to the following:

```
git fetch origin <current branch>
git merge origin/<current branch>
```

It is recommended to do these individually to avoid unwanted merge commits. This can be done like so

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/<branch> *
git rebase <branch> *
git checkout <branch> *
git merge origin/<branch> *
```

* Only have to do if there are any changes

If you want to see the status of all of your local and remote branches try this:

```
git log --oneline --all --decorate --graph
```

You can alias this as gg to make it easier.

Comment: Or you could just do `git pull --rebase`

Comment: Feel free to use that, however, I think it's better for a new users understanding if they can separate the acts of fetching, merging and pushing.

Answer (score 1):

git pull gets the latest from the origin alias for your current branch.
If you have any un-merged changes, it also merges them in your local machine